# Macro expansion in C

Tags: c, xcode, macros, c-preprocessor

This macro

```
#define f(x) x x
     f (1
     #undef f
     #define f 2
     f)
```

Expands to this `1 2 1 2` according to [this link](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/gcc-4.0.1/cpp/Directives-Within-Macro-Arguments.html#Directives-Within-Macro-Arguments).

It actually does this, I’ve verified with `Xcode Product > Perform Action > Preprocess` but what steps does the preprocessor follow while expanding this macro?

Comment: Are you not satisfied with my answer?

Comment: @Étienne fixed. Thank you for explaining. I learned from this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initial situation:

```
f (1
#undef f
#define f 2
f)
```

If we refer to the link you provided, the macro is preprocessed in 2 steps:
**Step 1: argument pre-expansion**

> If, within a macro invocation, that macro is redefined, then the new
>   definition takes effect in time for argument pre-expansion

Replacement of `f`, used as argument to the function-like macro, by 2:

```
f(1 f) -> f (1 2)
```

**Step 2: argument replacement**

> but the original definition is still used for argument replacement

Resolution of the function-like macro `f` using its original definition:

```
f(1 2) -> 1 2 1 2
```

The whole thing is actually equivalent to the following:

```
#define f(x) x x  
#define g 2
f(1 g)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that what happens is as following, to be able to better visualize the steps let’s rewrite the `#define` statement by adding distinguishing parentheses.

#### Step 0

```
#define f(x) (x) [x]

f (1
#undef f
#define f 2
f)
```

// Note, this does not produce a valid C code. I’m playing with it to understand the actions taken by the preprocess, not to get it compiled. View the results of the preprocessor via Product > Action > Preprocess as I’ve shown above.

So, first step taken by the preprocessor is substitution, x is being replaced by the value provided in the statement (this case, “1”), there are 2 times x in the macro values, so the same substitution happens twice. The (), and [] brackets are here to help distinguish between the 2 paths:

#### Step 1

```
(1
#undef f
#define f 2
f) [1
    #undef f
    #define f 2
    f]
```

Then `#undef` the macro `f`, which **does** exist and redefine it as `f 2`

#### Step 2

```
(1 f) [1 f]
```

At the final step preform a simple substitution of `f` with the value it is currently carrying, which is in this case `2`

#### Step 3

```
(1 2) [1 2]
```

That’s it. The expected result `1 2 1 2` has been substituted to the ground.